# Proving the Mandelbrot set is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove that the Mandelbrot set defined as the set $\mathcal M$ of complex numbers $c$: the recursive sequence defined as $$z_0=c, \space \space \space z_{n+1}={z_n}^2+c$$ is bounded.

Prove that $\mathcal M \subset \{|z|\leq 2\}$.

I've tried to show this by the absurd: take $c \in \mathcal M$ : $|c|>2$. Now I would like to show that the sequence $\{z_n\}_{n \in \infty}$ is unbounded. I need to show that for an arbitrary $M \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ there is $N \in \mathbb n$ such that if $n\geq N \implies |z_n|>M$. I am stuck, what could I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simplify notation, put $\gamma = |c|$. Suppose $\gamma > 2$. If $|z_n| \geq 2^n \gamma$, then
$$|z_{n+1}| \geq |z_n|^2 - \gamma \geq 2^{2n} \gamma^2 - \gamma \geq \left(2^{2n} - \frac{1}{2}\right)\gamma^2 \geq 2^{2n-1}\gamma^2 \geq 2^{n+1}\gamma.$$
Thus all $|z_n| \geq 2^{n}\gamma$ by induction. It follows that $c\not\in {\cal M}$.

Comment: I have this basic doubt: how do you get to the inequality $|z_{n+1}|\geq {|z_n|}^2-\gamma$?. I know that $|z_{n+1}|=|{z_n}^2+c|\leq |z_n|^2+\gamma$, but I am trying to deduce your inequality and I can't get to it.

Comment: @user156441: $|x+y| \geq |x| - |y|$.

Comment: A Comment per [new user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/410154/rivfader) @Rivfader: "According to their proof the sequence $f^{n}(5/2)$ should always exceed the sequence $2^{n}*5/2$, however $f^{1}(5/2)=15/4$ while $2^{1}*5/2=20/4$. The very last step $2^{2n-1}\gamma^{2} \geq 2^{n+1}\gamma$ is invalid for $n=0$."

Comment: Rivfader got the sign wrong on the initial condition (should be $c = -5/2$), but fundamentally, the closer you start to $-2$, the slower it is for the sequence to "get going", i.e. $\lvert z_n \rvert \geq 2^n \gamma$ fails to hold for all sufficiently small positive $n$. So we still need to prove that a base case with $n > 0$ is eventually satisfied.